# Expected catch() or return (promise/catch-or-return)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint

I am new to JavaScript.This is my first function in javascript to deploy a function on the firebase.

Got this error:

```
 - [eslint] Unexpected function expression. (prefer-arrow-callback)
 - [eslint] Expected catch() or return (promise/catch-or-return)
```

What is wrong with this function?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.grantSignupReward = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/last_signin_at')
  .onCreate(event => {
  var uid = event.params.uid;

  admin.database().ref('users/${uid}/referred_by')
    .once('value').then(function(data) {
    var referred_by_somebody = data.val();

    if (referred_by_somebody) {
      var moneyRef = admin.database()
      .ref('/users/${uid}/inventory/pieces_of_eight');

      moneyRef.transaction(function(current_value) {
        return (current_value || 0) + 50;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Those are not errors, they are warnings from the linter.

Comment: You can find explanations of the rules at https://eslint.org/docs/rules/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The first error suggests you to use an arrow function as a callback. So you need to replace the regular functions, `(function() { ... })`, with arrow functions, `(() => { ... })`.

The second error suggests that you either need to catch the promise rejection, or return the promise itself. I am not too sure about your code but I believe that this method:

```
admin.database().ref('users/${uid}/referred_by').once('value')
```

returns a promise. So it needs to be returned like this:

```
return admin.database().ref('users/${uid}/referred_by').once('value')
```

or handle the error like this:

```
admin.database().ref('users/${uid}/referred_by').once('value')
  // ... your code here
  .catch(error => { ... });
```

As @Bergi pointed out in the comments that returning the promise is not preferable here, you may just add a `catch` block to your promise.

Comment: You might want to add that `return`ing the promise is not appropriate here.

Comment: @Bergi -- I am afraid, I'm not familiar with the functions used here. That's why posted a diplomatic answer.

Comment: thanks @31piy .Actually I don't know anything about javascript.But your answer helped me lot.

Answer (score 3):

In order to solve `promise/catch-or-return`, just add a `.catch(() => null)` at the end of the line. And of course, don't forget to actually implement the error handling logic at some point in the not-so-distant future.